# onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) not getting called

Tags: kotlin, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout

I am currently using a custom view that extends a Constraint layout but I it does not trigger this overridden method in the view onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) not sure what went missing.

```
  class TestCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context,
  attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
  defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {


    init {


    }
    //This method one not get called
    override fun onApplyWindowInsets(insets: WindowInsets): WindowInsets {
    return super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets)
        val statusBarHeight = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
    }


    override fun fitSystemWindows(insets: Rect): Boolean {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      // Intentionally do not modify the bottom inset. For some reason,
      // if the bottom inset is modified, window resizing stops working.
      insets.left = 0
      insets.top = 0
      insets.right = 0
    }
    return super.fitSystemWindows(insets)
  }


}
```

Comment: anyone got any idea?

Comment: Ok, great! I think you can post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the insets are consumed, propagation down the hierarchy stops. It looks like something higher up is consuming what's available. See [`isConsumed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets.html#isConsumed()) of **WindowsInset**.

> Check if these insets have been fully consumed.
>
> Insets are considered "consumed" if the applicable consume* methods have been called such that all insets have been set to zero. This affects propagation of insets through the view hierarchy; insets that have not been fully consumed will continue to propagate down to child views.

Comment: is there some way to detect top inset for all views?

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38942268/6287910

Comment: @CheticampThank you for the response. In my case, I have a base activity and I try with ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView.rootView) but this cause back button system layout overlaying my view.

Comment: Cool Finally managed to solve it .                                                               
 /*From the Base Activity pass this as view but if I use window.decorView.rootView will have issues bottom bar overlays.*/
                                                                                                                              val containerView = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
 ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(containerView) { _, insets ->
    statusBarHeight = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
    insets
    }

Comment: btw @Cheticamp  is there a way to reset inset consumption? any method available to reset it.

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda Not that I know of.

Answer (score 6):

I found that without the `android:windowTranslucentStatus` property set to `true`, `onApplyWindowInsets` is never called.  I discovered this on reading [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933656/onapplywindowinsets-for-keyboard-not-called-if-windowtranslucentstatus-is-false).

In `styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="ExampleTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

I would love to understand why this is so, and if there is a way to have it called without requiring this attribute change.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you wanna reset it's windowInsets callback state, you should change `sysUiVisibility` params to let `fitsSystemWindows` work normally. Because `fitsSystemWindows` is a key to consume the windowInsets. You can learn more from android source code, of course, you need time.